# Add column to empty data.table in R

Tags: r, data.table

For adding a new column to an existing empty *data.table* (*version 1.8.6*) there seems to be no way to do it without being warned.

Example:

```
dt<-old.table[0]
dt[,new_column:=""]
```

This produces the warning:

```
In '[.data.table'(dt, , ':='(new_column,"")):    
Supplied 1 items to be assigned to 0 items of column 'new_column' (1 unused)
```

Is there a way to add a new column without warnings?

Answer (score 34):

Good question. Assign an empty character vector (`character()`) rather than a length 1 character vector (`""`).

```
> DT = data.table(a=1:3,b=4:6)
> DT2 = DT[0]
> DT2
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 2 cols: a,b
> DT2[,newcol:=character()]    # no warning
> DT2
Empty data.table (0 rows) of 3 cols: a,b,newcol
> sapply(DT2,class)
          a           b      newcol 
  "integer"   "integer" "character"
```

Btw, `""[0]` is another way to create a 0 length character vector; 7 characters less typing than `character()` but possibly less readable, depending on your preference.

Comment: What about just DT2[,newcol:=NA]  ? Is it the same?

Comment: No `NA` is not the same for two reasons. i) `NA` is type `logical` not `character` (`NA_character_` is type character) and ii) `NA` is length 1 not length 0.

Comment: I would like to have a column without data just to separate (split the table in two) the other when I print them as pdf wth xtable. Is it the same for me?

Comment: The original question here is about empty data (i.e. no rows).  Sounds like you have a table with data in it (nrow > 0).  So you can just use DT[, spacerCol:=" "].  You can also have blank column names on such spacer columns if you wish.

Answer (score 8):

Just as an addition how to add an empty character column, when the `data.table` has an arbitrary number of rows (including 0):

```
DT2[ ,newcol:=character(.N) ]
```

Comment: why is DT2$newcol=as.character(NA), assigned as 'logical'?